# How to fetch local JSON file and use export/import (modules) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, export, fetch-api, es6-modules

First problem:

I want to fetch local json file (in the same directory) but i get an error saying:
TypeError: Failed to parse URL from inputForHw3.json

```
fetch('inputForHw3.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => console.log(json))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

What I am doing wrong there?

Second problem:
When using modules (export/import) it says that i need to include type: module in package.json but when i type it there it runs only the code which is in main .js file (i have multiple .js files). How can I use export/import in multiple .js files but run them separately?

Please help :).

Comment: for fist problem you can try `./` before `inputForHw3.json`

Comment: Its showing the same error:
TypeError: Failed to parse URL from inputForHw3.json

Comment: Can you please check your file name? Is it right or you are mistaking something?

Comment: No, nothing wrong with the file name :(

Comment: `TypeError: Failed to parse URL from inputForHw3.json` is that the exact error? sounds non-english, why would something try to parse an URL **from** a file? (this is in nodejs as well?)

Comment: as for Second problem ... what? you import using `import` keyword and export using `export` keyword ... it's fully documented

Comment: Yes, its the exact error and yes its in node.js(debug console). As for the second problem you probably didnt understand me.

Comment: fetch won't work on node.js(debug console). It's a browser api. To do that you can use package like axios, node fetch.

Answer (score 0):

From what you posted, I can see the fetch function is unable to parse the URL correctly when trying to fetch the inputForHw3.json file.

Try:

```
fetch('./inputForHw3.json')
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((json) => console.log(json))
.catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

This should tell 'Fetch' what you're trying to do.